# Python/powershell? automation task on computer

Tags: python, powershell, automation

Case:
On computer i have program (file.exe) - a window will pop up and I will have to enter the IP address and press the "connect" button. Another window of the connected device is displayed - it shows the image (the device is recording the image) and some status.

And I would actually like to automate these activities that I described (something like what the robotask utility does, for example, etc.)

1. Run the program
2. Enter the IP address in the relevant input place
3. Press connect button
4. Make a screen-shot window with image and status.
5. And click the disconnect button

Can this be done in python, for example? Or powershell? Respectively can it be done? Or if not these two (python, powershell), then how for example?

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow (it contains no code and no question about that code). But you might want to look at AutoHotKey, it's quite useful for general automation on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the typical problem solved by [RPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_process_automation). There are a lot of software free and non, used for executing repetive tasks e.g. [MS Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/it-it/robotic-process-automation/) with a low code approach. Anyway you can use Python if you want, is a good choice as it have a lot of modules for all kind of development purpose just a [little search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+rpa) about python RPA gives you a lot of tutorials and packages for this purpose.